# Concatenation, rounding, and dealing with nulls

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have the following table:

```
x        y
1        1
1        0
1     null
0        1
0        0
0     null
null     1
null     0
null  null
```

And I want to produce the following column:

```
z
11
10
1null
01
00
0null
null1
null0
nullnull
```

But I'm having difficulty dealing with the rounding that occurs when using `coalesce` to convert potential `null` values to `'null'`. Trying this:

```sql
select concat(cast(coalesce(x, 'null') as int), cast(coalesce(y, 'null') as int))
```

Gives me the error `Numeric value 'null' is not recognized`. Even a simple `select concat(cast(x as char), cast(y as char))` doesn't produce the desired results, although no error occurs.

Technically, the following works (using `REGEXP_REPLACE`). But this seems a bit hacky. Is there a better documented way of doing this?

```sql
select
  regexp_replace(concat(case when x is null then 'null' else x end, case when y is null then 'null' else y end), '\.[0]+', '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value are strings, not ints.  So, convert them to the right type:

```
select concat(coalesce(cast(x as varchar(255)), 'null'),
              coalesce(cast(y as varchar(255)), 'null')
             )
```

Note:  Not all databases support `varchar(255)` in this context and need something like `string` or `char`.